# Creating Comma Separated Values in Batch Scripting

Tags: windows, batch, csv

I have written a piece of code in Batch script which is somewhat like :

```
( 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get name
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get domain 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get manufacturer 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get model 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get username 
    wmic.exe /node:x.x.x.x computersystem get systemtype
) >> file.txt
```

The contents of `file.txt` are :

```
ABC123  
xyz.com  
Hewlett-Packard  
HP xw4400 Workstation  
ABC123\Administrator  
x64-based PC
```

I want above information to be stored in CSV format as follows :

```
ABC123 , xyz.com , Hewlett-Packard , HP xw4400 Workstation , ABC123\Administrator , x64-based PC
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Insert [echo](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/echo.mspx?mfr=true) statements between the wmic calls.

Comment: Okay. Let me try this too.

Comment: Commas are getting printed on new lines.

Answer (score 0):

echo -n #  -n     do not output the trailing newline

Forget echo, use printf and xarg with delimiter newline -d'\n'

```
$ cat file.txt 
ABC123
xyz.com
Hewlett-Packard
HP xw4400 Workstation
ABC123\Administrator
x64-based PC


$ cat file.txt | xargs  -d'\n' printf "%s , %s , %s , %s , %s , %s \n"
ABC123 , xyz.com , Hewlett-Packard , HP xw4400 Workstation , ABC123\Administrator , x64-based PC
```